# Why is this throwing a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have the following piece of code inside a for loop

```
MyClass myobj= new MyClass(customers, price);
System.out.println(myobj);
if (!myobj.equals(null)) { //same happesn with myobj != null
    System.out.println("not null");
}
myMethod(myobj);
```

myMethod body is:

```
private void myMethod(MyClass myobj) {
   if (myobj.totalDemand()) {
      //bla bla
   }
```

After running the code in Junit the line "if (myobj.totalDemand())" throws a NullPointerException, however the console prints "not null"

Comment: And the definition of `MyClass.totalDemand`? Or put the real stacktrace.

Comment: 100% NPE is inside totalDemand

Answer (score 3):

If you call `myobj.equals(null)`, there's no guarantee that the implementation of `equals()` for the class will not throw a `NullPointerException`, and if `myobj` is `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException` trying to invoke `.equals()` on a `null` object.

To test for `null`, use this code:

```
if (myobj == null)
```

and to test for not null, use this:

```
if (myobj != null)
```

Comment: As i noted in the question the same happens with (myobj != null)

Comment: As Alexander asked: can you provide the code for MyClass.totalDemand? It looks like your NPE is throw from that mehtod.

Comment: Actually an equals method that throws a NPE for a null object violates the equals contract - equals has to return false for null objects. In reality not really a problem, because usually your first line in equals is `o instanceof FooClass` and `instanceof` returns false for null (really useful that)

Answer (score 0):

If myobj is null you will get NullPointerException, and if it's not console will print out "not null".
So, is there anything in variables customers and price in EVERY invoke cycle ?